Celery + Redis + Python: WorkerLostError(billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT) Job: 0.)
While trying to use Celery with Redis as the broker for my FastAPI application, where each endpoint makes use of memory-intensive functions with diffusers models, now I am facing an error saying

WorkerLostError(billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT) Job: 0.)

whenever I use --pool=prefork.
This does not appear when I use --pool=solo, but with that there is no use of --concurrency argument, but I need to make sure that the --concurrency=3 is achieved as its a production-grade application and many people will be accessing it at a time. So, I need to have it process 3 requests at a time.
Here's the error trace:
2024-07-08T12:45:12.751006109Z malloc(): unaligned tcache chunk detected
2024-07-08T12:45:13.000818714Z [2024-07-08 12:45:13,000: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-1' pid:1010 exited with 'signal 6 (SIGABRT)'
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017095419Z [2024-07-08 12:45:13,014: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT) Job: 0.')
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017111918Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017116005Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1264, in mark_as_worker_lost
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017119242Z     raise WorkerLostError(
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017122614Z billiard.einfo.ExceptionWithTraceback: 
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017125314Z """
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017128427Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017130962Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1264, in mark_as_worker_lost
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017133636Z     raise WorkerLostError(
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017136084Z billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT) Job: 0.
2024-07-08T12:45:13.017139686Z """

PS: I have sufficient memory and processing power on my server with powerful GPUs and multi-core CPUs, running this in a docker with supervisor as the CMD command to trigger celery and uvicorn/gunicorn together.

Did you check dmesg output to verify that OOM handler killed one or more worker processes? From personal experience, this typically happens when machine runs out of memory and OOM handler starts killing Celery worker processes that allocated too much RAM.
